# A word seems to be written in an unusual way in Psalm 60,2

Tags: hebrew, tehilim-psalms, aleph-bet-letters, mesorah-tradition

Why is there a medial mem rather than a final mem at the end of the word "aram" in Psalm 60:2? (Please see screenshot below.)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: From where is your screenshot taken?

Comment: I second @GeminiMan's comment — I checked every TaNaKh I have on paper and online and all of them had the final mem. I suspect this is a typesetting error.

Comment: Ok I guess it's a bug in my iphone app (BibleStudy).

Answer (score 5):

Neither the Leningrad nor Aleppo codices have that spelling.  Nor does the Mikraot Gedolot haKeter critical edition.

As per @NoamSienna, it appears your version has an error.